# What is a minimal surface of finite topology?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

For example this paper uses that term: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07793v1.pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A (necessarily non-compact) surface is said to have *finite topology* if it is homeomorphic to a compact surface (i.e., has finite genus) with finitely many points removed (i.e., has finitely many ends).

For minimal surfaces, complete examples embedded in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ include:

- Genus zero, one end: A plane (finite total curvature) or helicoid (infinite total curvature).
- Genus zero, two ends: A catenoid.
- Genus one, three ends: [Costa's surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costa's_minimal_surface). Generalizations of arbitrary finite genus and with three or more ends are known to exist.

Non-examples include:

- Doubly-periodic: [Scherk surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scherk_surface).
- Triply-periodic [Schwarz surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_minimal_surface).